# How to fix Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null in node?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ember.js

I am trying to create a web page application using node, ember and mongodb  which is able to edit or to delete the existing songs on my database, the webpage is already able to display the songs and to add new ones. The problem occurs when I click on my "EDIT" link next to a song - it throws "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null" when it's supposed to fetch me a song by it's id.

Here's my app/routes.js code:

```
...
router.route('/songs/:song_id')
 .put(function(req, res) { songs.updateSong(req, res, req.params.song_id) })
 .delete(function(req, res) { songs.deleteSong(req, res, req.params.song_id) });
...
```

Here's my api/song.js code:

```
...
module.exports.findById = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.params.id);
  Song.findById(req.params.id ,function(err, data){
    if(err){console.log(err);}
    console.log(data);
    return res.send({
      song: data
    });
  });
};
...
```

Here's my app/router.js code:

```
...
var SongSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  artist: String,
  year: Number,
  genre: String,
  lyrics: String
});
...
app.get('/api/songs/:id', function(req, res){
  console.log(req.params.id);
  Song.findById(req,res ,function(err, docs){
    if(err) res.send({error:err});
    else res.send({data:docs, "Song":"song"});
  });
});
...
```

templates/song.hbs

```
...
{{#each model as |song|}}
  <li>
    <b>{{song.artist}} - {{song.title}}  {{#link-to 'edit' song.id}}EDIT{{/link-to}} </b><br>
    ID:<i>{{song._id}}</i> <br>
    Released: {{song.year}} <br>
    Genre: {{song.genre}} <br>
    Lyrics:<br> "{{song.lyrics}}"<br><br>
   </li>
{{/each}}
...
```

Here's my controllers/edit.js

```
...

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  actions: {
    save: function() {
      var d = this.get('model');
      d.save();
      this.transitionToRoute('song');
    },
    del: function() {
      this.get('model').deleteRecord();
      this.transitionToRoute('song');
      this.get('model').save();
    }
  }
});
...
```

Comment: none of code that You've put in Your question does not have an object and `.id` property usage. please provide method that responsible for `edit` method (not update, not delete)

Comment: Let's explain again: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of null"`  this kind of error happens when You try to get id from object:  `someObject.id` and that object is `null`. So please find that code where it has `.id` property usage and add some handler to avoid `null` object.

Comment: That must be app/router.js code. I apologise for my frustration getting the best of me..

Comment: I wrote an answer, please check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After getting [GitHub](https://github.com/ChewOps/musicKursaDarbs/) link from You I saw that You've errors in code which leads to unknown behavior.

Simply replace `app/routes.js` with following content:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const SongsController = require('../api/songs');

const SongSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: String,
  artist: String,
  year: Number,
  genre: String,
  lyrics: String
});

const Song = mongoose.model('song', SongSchema);

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.get('/api/songs', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const songs = await Song.find({}).lean();
      res.status(200).send({songs});
    } catch(error) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: error.message
      });
    }
  });

  app.get('/api/songs/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const song = await Song.findById(req.params.id).lean();
      if(!song) {
        return res.status(404).send({
          message: "Song not found",
          params: req.params
        });
      }
      res.status(200).send({song});
    } catch(error) {
      res.status(500).send({
        message: error.message
      });
    }
  });


  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

  app.post('*', SongsController.addSong);
};
```

P.S. Quick fix is simply to pass handling to `SongsController.findById` method that already written:

```
app.get('/api/songs/:id', SongsController.findById);
```

Comment: @Dilbert You're checking result of error on ember, but before ember there is system error that server responds. Expand line with error above that shows `500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: what's on `api/songs.js` line `15`   and `app/routes.js` line `44` screenshots please

Comment: app/routes.js line 44 is the line where the try {..} and api/songs.js 15 is this line   console.log(req.params.id);  you suggested earlier begins. deleted the link by accident earlier https://i.imgur.com/rhQfttC.png

Comment: which framework YOu're using? express? cause `req.params` is default attribute of request context

Comment: Yes. Im using Express. I actualy followed these tutorial series step by step but somehow what worked for the author doesn't work for me. https://www.programwitherik.com/how-to-setup-your-ember-project-with-mongo-and-node/

Comment: @Dilbert I see... tutorial is correct, seems like YOu cannot adapt examples to Your own code

Comment: @Dilbert can You put YOur code to github or somewhere? Cause I cannot understand what You've done even by code parts in Your question.

Comment: @Dilbert so You've mixed tutorial with classic expresjs way usage, tutorial is correct, You're not reading tutorial carefully. That's why it's unpredictable what You're doing. So simply put Your modified files back as it was and simply add `router.route('/api/songs/:id')...` as in **UPDATE** section of my answer

Comment: I messed up copying the repository however here's the original https://github.com/ChewOps/musicKursaDarbs/

Comment: @Dilbert You've messed up everything (:  I've updated my answer, simply replace `Song` to `SongModel` and try again.

Comment: WARNING: Encountered "id" in payload, but no model was found for model name "id" (resolved model name using (unknown).modelNameFromPayloadKey("id"))   and the same warning appears for rest of the attributes but the original error remains

Comment: @Dilbert I said to replace `Song` to `SongModel` in `app/routes.js` (at line 45). By screenshot that You put it points to line `63` which still uses wrong code. Make sure YOu've put latest code to github.

Comment: No more errors from node! Thank you for your endless patience!